# What tool are you using to tidyup yourhtml and css code?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a tool to optimize/tidy up my CSS and HTML (align lines of codes correctly, remove empty spaces, etc). I've seen a lot of tools on google but wanted to have the feedback of experienced people. Many thanks

Comment: I use my IDE, PhpStorm. It does the job nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Adobe Dreamweaver there is something called

apply source formatting

it does the job